# Selenium Webdriver - Upload functionality not working due to Add button being invisible

Tags: java, user-interface, file-upload, selenium

Summary: 
In Selenium Webdriver - Upload functionality is not working due to Add button being invisible.

Description:

The functionality is like, a pop up window opens for upload file, initially Add button is disable. The user needs to click on browse button, select the file and the system validates for the file format and size (4MB). If its valid then the browse text box is highlighted in green. After validation only, Add button gets enabled. On clicking Add, pop up closes and added material is displayed in main page.

Selenium Code and Error:

But below se code throws error with the error - org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with.

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='fuVideo_ctl02']").sendKeys("D:\\Featured         Materials");
Thread.sleep(1000);            
driver.findElementByClassName("add_uploadbtn").click(); //Clicking on Add button
String Addtext = driver.findElementByClassName("add_uploadbtn").getText();
```

System.out.println("Add text" +Addtext);

Above Print Statement Result: 
Add text

Note: While the script is running, document is uploaded and file validation starts and doesnt end..its showing for sometime and scripts ends with above mentioned error.

HTML:
Upload functionality code till Add button

```
<td colspan="2">
<span id="fuVideo" class="upload_file_txt mleft10" style="background: white"    onclick="javascript:fnCheckFileIsUpload(this);">
<input id="fuVideo_ctl00" class="upload_file_txt" type="hidden" name="fuVideo$ctl00" style="width: 550px;" value="Copy of CAS QEA-PES Score Card Feb_2014_Capex  Opex_STORM_Updated.xlsx">
<div id="fuVideo_ctl01" name="fuVideo_ctl01">
<input id="fuVideo_ctl02" class="upload_file_txt" type="file" style="width: 550px; background-color: Lime; color: black;" name="fuVideo$ctl02">
</div>
</span>
<br disabled="disabled">
<span style="margin-left: 25px;">Description</span>
<input id="txtDescriptionFU" class="add_edit_content_input" type="text" style="margin-left: 20px; width: 460px;" maxlength="500" name="txtDescriptionFU">
<input id="btnVideo" class="add_uploadbtn" type="button" onclick="javascript:fnFileUploadValidation();" value="Add">
```

Pls. help to solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance ....

Answer (score 0):

1 second doesn't seem like enough time for the Add button to become visible. Instead of `Thread.sleep(1000)`, use:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, MAX_WAITTIME_IN_SECONDS);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("add_uploadbtn").click();
```

This assumes that `driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='fuVideo_ctl02']").sendKeys("D:...` is working properly.